# SQLite: What can cause indexing to fail?

Tags: sqlite, indexing, output, terminate

This is a very general question:

Can you think of a reason why the following would break on very large tables (> 1 billion rows)?

```
sqlite3 sample_DB.db "CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS sample_index ON sample_table(sample_row)"
```

I have tried this a couple of times and it seems that it does not even give any error message, but the processing stops **at some point** and there is no index upon `.schema`.

The hard-disk is not running full. There is basically no memory consumption in the processing and if there were, there is plenty available.

The database is more than 800GB large, but I thought that the file-limit for ext4 is 2TB.

In the current state of the database:

- `PRAGMA page_size` returns `4096`
- `PRAGMA page_count` returns `185974887`
- `PRAGMA max_page_count` returns `1073741823`
- `PRAGMA freelist_count` returns `0`

Comment: You have a syntax error because you don't specifiy which column(s) to index... https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html

Comment: Sorry I do not have the syntax error in the real code, let me fix this here...

Comment: That's better. Next question: what's the page size and max page count (and current number of pages)?

Comment: What about `PRAGMA max_page_count`?

Comment: (I'm wondering if there's enough page capacity left to hold the index you're trying to make)